# acrobat X pro textbox tool keeps reverting to default color/font after program is closed and opened again

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

As above :

is there a way to make the settings for the 'Add Text' tool in Acrobat X stick? For now, it always goes back to Black, Minion Pro font if i close the program and launch another PDF.

also, is there a keyboard shortcut for the Add Text tool?
p.s. it's the one with the built-in alignment tool, not the old, rudimentary add text tool.

Comment: the same problem goes to the viewing mode for acrobat X. each time i just want the toolbar to be on (i.e. excluding the left-hand sidebar and the topmost (File/etc) bar, it reverts to the standard display setting.

Comment: anyone knows????

Comment: anyone knows?...